# $\mathcal{M}= \lbrace A \subseteq X | A \: \mbox{or} A^{c} \: \mbox{is numerable} \rbrace$ is a $\sigma$ algebra generated by a singleton family

Tags: real-analysis, probability, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X \neq \emptyset$ and $$\mathcal{M}= \lbrace A \subseteq X | A \: \mbox{or} A^{c} \: \mbox{is numerable} \rbrace.$$

I want to prove that $\mathcal{M}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the family $$\mathcal{A}= \lbrace \lbrace x \rbrace | x \in X \rbrace.$$

They way I proceed is to define

$$\mathcal{F}= \lbrace S \subset \mathcal{P}(X) | S \: \mbox{is}\: \sigma \mbox{-algebra} \: \mbox{and} \: \mathcal{A} \subseteq S  \rbrace. $$

So what I wanted to prove is the following equality

$$\mathcal{M}= \cap \lbrace S \mid S \in \mathcal{F} \rbrace.$$

If Im right so far, which I think I am. I got problems proving both inclusions. Here is my attempt:

For $\mathcal{M} \subseteq \cap \lbrace S | S \subset \mathcal{F} \rbrace$, I take $B \in \mathcal{M}$ so by definition of $\mathcal{M}$ I got that $B$ is numerable or $B^{c}$ is numerable. Let suppose $B$ is numerable, as $B \subset X$ and $B \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ by transitivity $B \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ but I dont see how to see that $B$ is $\sigma$-algebra and that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq B$. The same problem if I suppose $B^{c}$ is numerable.

For $\cap \lbrace S | S \subset \mathcal{F} \rbrace \subset \mathcal{M}$, I take $E \in \cap \lbrace S | S \subset \mathcal{F}\rbrace$. This means $E \in S$ for very $S \subset \mathcal{F}$, then $S \in \mathcal{F}$ so $S$ is $\sigma$ algebra and $\mathcal{A} \subset S$ but I dont know ow to proceed here in order to show $E \subset X$ and $E$ or $E^{c}$ is numerable.

Also any help in order to answer if $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{P}(X)$? would be also apreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Uhm... Nowhere the definition suggests that $B\in \mathcal M\Rightarrow B\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$. Fortunately so.

Comment: @Gae.S. For the last question right?Nice!.  Hmm, for the other contention im not sure at all since I can not find  and $X \neq \emptyset$ such  there is $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ which $A$ not numerable neither $A^{c}$ not numerable.

Comment: @cos I am referring to: "For $\mathcal{M} \subseteq \cap \lbrace S | S \subset \mathcal{F} \rbrace$, I take $B \in \mathcal{M}$ so by definition of $\mathcal{M}$ I got that $B$ is numerable or $B^{c}$ is numerable. Let suppose $B$ is numerable, as $B \subset X$ and $B \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ by transitivity $B \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ but I dont see how to see that $B$ is $\sigma$-algebra and that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq B$."

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be in $\mathcal{M}$ and let $S$ be any $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$. If $M$ is countable it's a countable union of singletons, all of which are in $S$ and so $M \in S$. Otherwise it's the complement of a countable set (which is in $S$ as saw) and so also in $S$ (as $S$ is closed under complements).

This show the left to right inclusion.

On the other hand, note that $\mathcal{M}$ itself (being a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal{A}$) is among the $\sigma$-algebras we take the intersection of so $\bigcap \{S: S \in \mathcal{F}\} \subseteq \mathcal{M}$ is trivial, the intersection of a family is a subset of any of its members.